# Divide case in set operation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Show that for all sets the following equations hold
$A -(B-C) = (A-B) \cup (A\cap C)$

**Solution.** Take $x \in A -(B-C)$, if $x \notin (B-C)$, then either $x\notin B$ or $x\in C$. In the first case, $x\in A-B$, in the second, $x\in A\cap C$. Conversely, if $x\in A-B$, then $x\notin B$, so $x\notin B-C$, so $x\in A-(B-C)$. If $x\in A\cap C$, then $x\notin B-C$

The proof makes sense to me. But in this part "if $x \notin (B-C)$, then either $x\notin B$ or $x\in C$.", I got $x\notin B$ or $x\in C \iff x \notin (B-C)$. But $-B \cap C$ may not be $\emptyset$, that is, this proof may check the same area twice(which is unnecessary). I checked dividing case to $x\notin B \cup C$ or $x\in C$($-(B\cup C) \cap C = \emptyset$) and $x\notin B$ or $x\in B\cap C$($-B \cap (B \cap C) = \emptyset$) also prove the given statement. I want to ask is it common to divide the case like in the solution? Do you think my approach is better?

Comment: Cases may overlap, yes (and it's common). I don't like that the solution used the word "either" since mathematicians use the inclusive-or by default.

Comment: "that is, this proof may check the same area twice(which is unnecessary)"  Why would you worry about checking a same area twice?  You aren't actually looking at any specific elements and *doing* any work on them.  You have a broad general way of doing one set based on its defining characteristic, and you have another way for the other set.  Why worry about overlap? "Do you think my approach is better?" Um, to be blunt, absolutely not.  You are adding more work to do and more restrictions for utterly no reason and you add no more clarity.

Comment: ... that said...  An alternative "scorched earth" approach can work on these problems where you divide the universe into a partition of the eight basic components (based on elements that are either in or not in A,B,C) and stating which of the eight components each side is.  But that is never elegant and if there is a shorter cleaner proof (which the texts certainly is) you should go with that.

Comment: I find your use of the word "unnecessary" interesting.  I'd say it is unnecessary to check $-B\cap C$ because it is a subset of $C$ and will be checked when we check $C$.  I guess it's a matter what we imagine the work of checking is.  You seem to view this as going to airport security and imagine they open each bag and open each one and look at each item. You say "when you check bag $B\cap C$ again, you already did this". I see it more as a single swipe scan "When you scan C just swipe over $B\cap C$ again; It'll save me the work of unpacking". Which model is more accurate do you think?

Comment: @fleablood Your "airport security" example well described what I thought. And yes, as your first comment, regardless of proving the statement with or without overlapping I don't do more work actually(and even the first method can be preferable). I just expressed my thought and wanted to hear other people's opinion about it. So thanks a lot.

Comment: for set operations, $-B \cap C$ has no meaning, the $-$ symbol cannot be unary.

Comment: @LoutchoGlotuk Yes, I used $-B$ as $S-B$ when any set in consideration is a subset of S. It is my book's way to express complement. Later I should write $B^\complement$ instead of $-B$.